# Julia Plots のheatmapのcbarの余計な部分を非表示にする方法

Tags: julia

下図のカラーバーで0以下の値を非表示にしたいのですが、うまくいきません。
[Plotsのドキュメント](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/) を見てもどこにも書いてないのですが、pyplot等の他のパッケージを使用したうまいやり方などないでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: プロットした際のコードなどを質問文に含めた方がより親切かと思います。

Comment: その範囲のデータは存在するが非表示にしたい、ということでしょうか？　そうで無いならば古い記事ですが(plotly系を使えば?) z軸のデータを収めたい範囲(0～0.175?)に調整すれば出来るのでは？ [True heat maps #147](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/147)